# How to reference a resource file correctly for JAR and Debugging?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a nasty problem referencing resources when using a Maven project and Jar files...

I have all my resources in a dedicated folder /src/main/resources which is part of the build path in Eclipse. Files are referenced using

```
getClass().getResource("/filename.txt")
```

This works fine in Eclipse but fails in the Jar file - there the resources are located in a folder directly below the jar's root...

Does anyone know a 'best practice' to reference a file both in the JAR and (!) in Eclipse?

**Edit:**
The problem is that while the resources actually are located in the JAR in a folder "resources" at the top level, the above method fails to find the file...

Comment: What is the folder that is used in the jar file?  /resources ?

Comment: *This works fine in Eclipse but fails in the Jar file - there the resources are located in a folder directly below the jar's root...* which is exactly what should happen. Where's the problem?

Comment: You should be developing the same way whether running your code from an IDE or from "the JAR" - i.e., if you expect to load resources from the classpath in your IDE, you should be able to load resources from the classpath when run externally as well!

Comment: The exactly same line(also using the file then) throws an Exception (NullPointer) - so the file is not found... Although it physically is there!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The contents of Maven resource folders are copied to target/classes and from there to the root of the resulting Jar file. That is the expected behaviour.

What I don't understand is what the problem is in your scenario. Referencing a Resource through `getClass().getResource("/filename.txt")` starts at the root of the classpath, whether that (or an element of it) is `target/classes` or the JAR's root. The only possible error I see is that you are using the wrong `ClassLoader`.

Make sure that the class that uses the resource is in the same artifact (JAR) as the resource and do `ThatClass.class.getResource("/path/with/slash")` or `ThatClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("path/without/slash")`.

But apart from that: if it isn't working, you are probably doing something wrong somewhere in the build process. Can you verify that the resource is in the JAR?

Comment: sounds like his resource files are not being compiled into the JAR, somehow

Comment: Ah, the important part is missing, sorry: The files are actually in the JAR, but there is a NullPointerException as the file is not found using the getClass().getResource("/filename.txt")...

Comment: @Patrick are you sure you are using the correct case? If you use windows, the file system is not case sensitive, but a JAR file is...

Comment: @Sean: Yes, they are all are using camelCase. I checked again but they seem to be correct...

Comment: Both the ThatClass.class.getResource("/path/with/slash") and ThatClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("path/without/slash") work fine in Eclipse - but fail in the JAR... Do it explicitly need to add the folder in the JAR to a 'JAR-path' (if such a thing exists)?

Comment: No. If the Jar is on the classpath you don't need to add anything

Comment: Thanks, the getClass().getResourceAsStream("/folder/file.xml") - worked for me!

Answer (score 43):

Once you pack the JAR, your resource files are not files any more, but stream, so `getResource` will not work!

Use `getResourceAsStream`.

To get the "file" content, use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html:

```
static public String getFile(String fileName)
{
        //Get file from resources folder
        ClassLoader classLoader = (new A_CLASS()).getClass().getClassLoader();

        InputStream stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);

        try
        {
            if (stream == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot find file " + fileName);
            }

            return IOUtils.toString(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            System.exit(1);
        }

        return null;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It explains why `getResource` does not work and lists an alternative, if you need them, but frankly wrapping it in `InputStreamReader` works fine.

Comment: Is there Java documentation for this behavior somewhere?  I spent WAY too much time on this problem...

Answer (score 24):

I had a similar problem.
After a full day of trying every combination and debugging I tried getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/filename.txt") and got it to work finally.
Nothing else helped.

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` is indeed worth a try, not just for possibly shortening your code. For me `ThatClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.txt")` worked. Prefixing "resources" doesn't make sense for me as the file was copied to the root of the JAR. One thing to remember though is that `getResourceAsStream` doesn't throw exceptions, but [returns null](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) if file can't be found.

Comment: Thanks, @YushinWashio this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the resources directory in the jar file (so it is under the /resources folder in the jar, and if /src/main is in your build path in eclipse, then you should be able to reference your file as:

```
getClass().getResource("/resources/filename.txt");
```

Which should work in both environments.

Comment: The folder is there in the jar and the build path in Eclipse is set to include the resources folder, but it strangely does not work...

Comment: omitting the /resources and starting with filename.txt or foldername/filename.txt worked for me

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that within the IDE the getClass().getResource("Path"); String is not CASE SENSITIVE when accessing a file but when running from a jar it is. Check your Capitalisation on directory compared to file. It does work. Also if you try new File(getClass().getResource("Path"); the file won't be readable outside IDE.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this method can help for some situations.

```
public static File getResourceFile(String relativePath)
{
    File file = null;
    URL location = <Class>.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    String codeLocation = location.toString();
    try{
        if (codeLocation.endsWith(".jar"){
            //Call from jar
            Path path = Paths.get(location.toURI()).resolve("../classes/" + relativePath).normalize();
            file = path.toFile();
        }else{
            //Call from IDE
            file = new File(<Class>.class.getClassLoader().getResource(relativePath).getPath());
        }
    }catch(URISyntaxException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Just copy the file to a temporary directory.

```
String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
File file = new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath(), "filename.txt");
if (!file.exists()) {
     InputStream is = (getClass().getResourceAsStream("/filename.txt"));
     Files.copy(is, file.getAbsoluteFile().toPath());
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the user has permission to write to tmpdir (or any other directory of your choosing) - especially if the JAR file is shared between many users. It's better to make the JAR self-contained if the resource is read-only,