# Error in loading object from InputStream in java while trying to open a jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a subreport which I have used in my main jasper report, I am sending the subreport from a java form using an `InputStream`, this is the code:

```
InputStream suprepo = getClass().getResourceAsStream("LinuxTest_subreport1.jasper");
```

And in the main report I have create a parameter that's class is `InputStream`, and accepting the value from my java form that I'm  passing using a hashmap.
My problem is that everything works fine when there is only 1 page, but as soon as there is more then one page I receive this error:

```
error in loading object from input stream
```

This is my jasper code

```
<parameter name="subrepopath" class="java.io.InputStream" isForPrompting="false"/>
```

Comment: Does the error happen on the line you are showing when you debug?

Comment: That subreport is part of a jasper book?

Comment: @Milaci yes it is a part of my main jasper

Comment: @serge the error is coming on this line

Comment: I'm out now and i can't try but i think that you should call only a main report and puttin on jasper the relative path of subreport.

Comment: `InputStream suprepo = getClass().getResourceAsStream("LinuxTest_subreport1.jasper");
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        
        parameters.put("kyid", jTextField1.getText());
        parameters.put("subrepopath", suprepo);
        String reportnme = "LinuxTest.jasper";

        InputStream sfilenme = getClass().getResourceAsStream(reportnme);
        try {
    "@serge the error is coming on this line -->"        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(sfilenme, parameters, con); `

Comment: @Milaci see my subreport jasper file and my main jasper file both are in the same project including my java form,since my subreport needs a relative path i am using inputstream because the jasper reports and the java form both are going to be in a jar file once i clean and build them

Comment: Subrepo i think that should be a path(String)  not an InputStream

Comment: @Milaci i agree with u , i tried passing a string but it does not get the path inside the jar

Comment: why not? Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6192661/2724934

Comment: @Milaci what you have sent me is also input stream only or url,there is no code to get the path inside of the jar and pass it as a string

Comment: I know, it is just an example that you can use path inside jar. Have you try to put a path and not inpitstream?

Comment: @Milaci had got success when the jasper file was out of the jar, so that time i use to pass the path of the jasper as a string, but my team leader doesn't want it that way he wants it through the jar only

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and it was caused by a subreport (.jasper) compiled with other version of the Jasper Report.

Comment: Holy answer, saved lot of time! Same here guys. Subreport compiled with version 6.4.0 not working in the version 6.20.x

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered from this issue and just recently found the solution thanks to [this post](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/504094/filling-subreport-multiple-times).

What you need to do is change your subreport type to Object:

```
<parameter name="subrepopath" class="java.lang.Object" isForPrompting="false"/>
```

In your SubReport properties, set the Expression class to be:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport
```

[image: Changing report type]

In your code, you need to load the object into a JasperReport object, this is where I differ from the linked page as the [methods used are deprecated](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperManager.html).

So you would do:

```
InputStream suprepo = getClass().getResourceAsStream("LinuxTest_subreport1.jasper");
JasperReport subJasperReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(suprepo);
```

Then add in your parameter map the object `subJasperReport` with the key of `subrepopath` and you'll find your multi page report will now generate correctly.