# resource correct path for Media from artifacts jar

Tags: java, javafx, path, media-player, filepath

```
 ProjectOne
|
|-----Out
|   |-----production
|   |------artifacts
|       |-----jar
|   
|
|-----src
|   |----pack1
|   |   |---Test.java
|   |
|   |----vid1.mp4
|
```

With the IDE .. All ways below are working fine :

```
 1-mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer(new Media(new File(getClass().getResource("/vid1.mp4").toURI().toString()).getPath()));

2- mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new 
Media(getClass().getResource(“vid1.mp4”).toURI().toString()));

3-mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media (new File 
 ("src/vid1.mp4").toURI ().toString ());
```

once I make artifacts jar , and want run it using same jre...the program starts, but the second stage where the resource vid1.mp4 should shows, not showing and program freezes obviously.

All above ways failed when calling the resource from the jar .
And used as well :

```
 mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new 
 Media(getClass().getResourceAsStream(“/vid1.mp4”)).toString());
```

based on ths link recommendations :
[How to reference a resource file correctly for JAR and Debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192661/how-to-reference-a-resource-file-correctly-for-jar-and-debugging)

what is the correct path to call the resources from the jar and use in the Media class. .

Comment: Did you check the JAR file? Make sure your resource has actually been added to the JAR.

Comment: @slaw...yes I unzipped the jar... All resources & . Class files there.

Comment: Try `new Media(getClass().getResource("/vid1.mp4").toExternalForm());`. If that doesn't work, then are you getting any exceptions when trying to load the resource? If so, please post the full stack trace.

Comment: @slaw..just tried... On IDE worked fine.... On artifacts jar, same story as before  :(

Comment: @slaw.. The first stage I added some images to the fxml file, stage shows in artifact.  On stage 2 I have video so needed to hard code in the controller.