# Code works fine, then after maven install, there are errors in both the jar and the IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, fxml

Exception in Application start method:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at edu.citytech.view.EmployeeMain.start(EmployeeMain.java:16)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application edu.citytech.view.EmployeeMain
```

Here's the class with the main method, EmployeeMain.java:

```
package edu.citytech.view;

import edu.citytech.utitlity.GlobalVariables;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EmployeeMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("EmployeeView.fxml")); 

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

        // * new *
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);   
        primaryStage.setTitle("Employee List");

        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(EmployeeMain.class.getResourceAsStream("People.jpg")));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        if (args.length > 0) {
            GlobalVariables.portNumber = (Integer.parseInt(args[0]));           
        }       

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And what fixes this is adding a space to any of the files and saving it, then restarting the Eclipse IDE, and running it again from the IDE. What breaks it is when I run mvn clean and mvn install, and then running the jar file it created. Everyone in my class is having this problem, and the teacher has no idea how to fix it. It just works for some people and it doesn't for others. However this time, this isn't working no matter what I try. Only works in the IDE until I use maven to create a jar. Then it won't work until I modify and save a file, and then restart the IDE. Everything is named properly and it just works and doesn't work randomly. Is this an IDE problem or a project problem?

What can I do so that I can make a jar file that works when it's run?

Comment: check that `EmployeeView.fxml` is included in your `jar`

Comment: That hits really close. It's actually not in the jar. Not unless I copy it to the src/main/resources. However it still won't work, I think it has to be in the same package as where the main method is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get it to work. Really annoying but really simple. I'm going to write it here for anyone who is probably finding this page through a search engine.

1. Right click on project folder > Maven > Update Project...
2. Update selected project
3. Right click the project folder and run in local terminal
4. mvn install

And DO NOT DO MVN CLEAN

Answer (score -1):

3 issues possible

1. it sounds like you need the IDE to recompile the code for it to work again in eclipse too? not sure why that would be actually unless its the java version used ...

eclipse usually rebuilds given any change (e.g. your space added to file)

is your eclipse IDE and maven compile are using the same java version?

delete your ./target directory and

add this to maven pom.xml to make sure you're using the right java version (e.g. for java 1.8):

```
    <properties>
         <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
         <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

2. include the file in the jar build

Also the copy your EmployeeView.fxml should be in src/main/resources and the file wont be making it into your jar file unless you include:

```
             <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
```

3. That code won't work within the jar file at runtime see these answers:
   [How to reference a resource file correctly for JAR and Debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192661/how-to-reference-a-resource-file-correctly-for-jar-and-debugging)

and update your code to use getREsourceAsStream e.g. here's a method i use:

```
public void load(String resource, HashSet<String> hashset) {
        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream is_awl = classloader.getResourceAsStream(resource);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is_awl));
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                hashset.add(line.trim());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("LexicalFeatures can't initialise:"
                    + resource + " hashset: "+ e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```